# Get ID automatically in input-field after <SELECT> without button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql-server

I have an SQL-database with many tables. Now I would like to create an input-form to be able to get data into the db without writing the entire sql-code every time. And this should work as follows:

All table names are listed in a drop-down menu. After having selected a table name, a new table with 4 columns is created automatically:

The first column of this table simply contains an increasing number.
The second column contains the field-names of the selected table.
In the third column there are empty input fields to enter the values for the database. Only in the third line (=product name) there is a drop-down menu with all product names from the main-table of the db.
The fourth column contains the data type (e.g. int or varchar)

[image: Here is an example of such a table]

All tables in the database have the same structure in the first 3 columns: the first column contains the table-id, the second column the foreign-key (=master_id) and the third column the product_name.

Up to this point, the script works well with the following 2 php-files (javasql.php and getuser.php):

javasql.php:

```
enter code here

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
       if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
     }
    </script>
     </head>
     <body>

    <form>


    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
             <option value="" class="optdrugs">please select</option>


    <?php

    include("files/zugriff.inc.php");  // database Access

    $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE
     TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'product'";
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo '<option class="optdrugs" value="'. $row['TABLE_NAME'] . '">' . 
    $row['TABLE_NAME']. '</option>';
       echo '<br>';
     }

     ?>

    </select>
    </form>

    <br>

     <div id="txtHint"><b>Bitte Tabelle ausw&auml;hlen:</b>
    <br>

     <?php

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

     $sent = $_POST['sent'];


     $q = $_POST['tablename'];
     $column_passed = unserialize($_POST['column']);  // content of array 
    $column is passed from getuser.php



    foreach ($_POST["insertvalue"] as $key => $value) {

        echo $value . "<br>";
        $werte[] = "'$value'";


    }

                     $sql="INSERT INTO $q ($column_passed) VALUES (" . 
    implode(", ", $werte) . ")";       // data entry                     
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

                    if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) > 0) {
                             echo "<h3 style='color:blue'>successful</h3>";
                             } else {
                             echo "<h3 style='color:red'>not 
    successful</h3>";
                             }


    }

    ?>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html> 


enter code here

    getuser.php:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
     }

      table, td, th {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 5px;
     }

      th {text-align: left;}
      </style>


      </head>
      <body>

     <form id="formdatabase" name="formdatabase" action="javasql.php" 
     method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="sent" value="yes">

     <?php

     $q = strval($_GET['q']);


      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','product');
      if (!$con) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

      mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
      $sql="SELECT * FROM $q";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $numcols = mysqli_num_fields($result);   // gets number of columns in result table
     $field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result); // gets the column names from the result table

     $data_type_array = array(
        1=>'tinyint',
        2=>'smallint',
        3=>'int',
        4=>'float',
        5=>'double',
        7=>'timestamp',
        8=>'bigint',
        9=>'mediumint',
        10=>'date',
        11=>'time',
        12=>'datetime',
        13=>'year',
        16=>'bit',
        252=>'text',
        253=>'varchar',
        254=>'char',
        246=>'decimal'
      );

       $data_type_array = array_flip($data_type_array);


       echo "<table>";


       echo "<tr>";
                                                                                       echo "<th>" . 'Nr' . "</th><th>" . 'Column names' . "</th>
       <th>" . 'Values for db-entry' . "</th><th>" . 'Type' . "</th>";
       echo "</tr>";
       echo "<tr>";

       $nr = 1;

       for($x=0;$x<$numcols;$x++):?>


        <td><?= $nr; ?></td>
        <td><?= $field[$x]->name; ?></td>
        <?= $column[] = $field[$x]->name; ?>
        <td>   


     <?php
              if ($field[$x]->name == 'Name') {     // if-Beginn
     ?>

              <select name="insertvalue[<?= $x; ?>]" id="insertvalue<?= 
              $x; ?>" size="1" onchange = "javascript:getSelectedRow()">

     <?php
              include("files/zugriff.inc.php");

              $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_main ORDER BY Name";
              $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo '<option class="optdrugs" value='. $row['Name'] . '>' . 
              $row['Name'] . '</option>';
              echo '<br>';
              }

      ?>

              </select>

      <?php

          $name_option = "";


     } else {

          $name_option = "<input type='text' id='insertvalue" . $x . "' 
          name='insertvalue[" . $x . "]' size='50'>";

        echo $name_option;
       }
     ?>


             </td>  


      <?php

               $key = array_search($field[$x]->type, $data_type_array);
          if($key !== false){
              echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
          }else{
              echo "<td>" . $field[$x]->type . "</td>";
          }

      ?>
                 <td><?= $field[$x]->type; ?></td>

                 <?= $nr = $nr + 1; ?>

                 </tr>


      <?php endfor;


       echo "</table>";

       mysqli_close($con);


       ?>

       <input type="hidden" name="tablename" value="<?= $q; ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="column" value="<?php echo htmlentities
            (serialize($column)); ?>">
       <input type="submit" value="Enter values" name="submit">

       </form>


       </body>
       </html>
```

Since I need the master_id (= foreign key) in addition to the product-name for database entry, I would like to extend my script, so that the respective master_id is automatically sent to the input field in line 2, when a product-name is selected in line 3 ... without clicking a button. I tried to do this with javascript but it didn´t work. As far as I know, the solution would be to use AJAX but unfortunately, I am not very used to AJAX. 
I would be more than happy, if someone could help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this script is not for public use, it is only for me to enter values into the db. The public db-access is done with PDO.

Comment: Why not just create an insert stored procedure for each table? Then you can use them and so can the front end. This seems way overly complicated for a typical mundane task like inserting data.

Comment: Thanks Sean, could you please give me an example for your suggested solution?